# Quasicrystals and their classification

Tags: group-theory

What is the most general updated mathematical classification of (1d)(2d)(3d) or more generally (Nd) quasicrystals? Is there an analogue classification for quasicrystals to that existing for crystalographic groups or the problem as stated here is currently "open"?